# Magento Home Page Featured Products - there are no products matching the selection

Tags: magento-1.9, home, featured-product

```
{{block type="featuredproducts/listing" template="featured/featuredproducts/list_home.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I have checked the `featuredproducts/listing` block type, seem that it is your custom block?

Comment: Do you mean featured products listing and enabled featured product to yes?

Comment: Without knowing where "featuredproducts" comes from (probably a 3rd party theme?) and without knowing the code, this is guesswork. Maybe you don't have "featured" products? Did you reindex and clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added products to the site?
Made sure they are active?

Also check to make sure they are listed in categories (Admin--->Catalog--->Manage Categories)

One of these could be the problem.  When I was creating a new site I had a similar issue before i realized the products were not listed under categories.

Comment: Products have been added and are enabled to be seen as featured products. Products are listed in categories